# Grouping rows and adding average of group values to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where I need to create a grouping of ages and then have the averages amount of `Tip amount` for each group.

My Data looks the following

| Tip amount | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 30 |
| 30 | 35 |
| 4 | 60 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 7 | 25 |
| 3 | 45 |
| 15 | 31 |
| 5 | 8 |

I have tried to use `pd.cut()` with `bins` to create the grouping, but I can't seem to get the `Tip amount` average (maybe using `mean()`) to be in the DataFrame as well.

```
import pandas as pd

bins= [0,15,30,45,60,85]
labels = ['0-14','15-29','30-44','45-59','60+']

df['Tip amount']=df['Tip amount'].astype(int)
#df = df.groupby('Age')[['Tip amount']].mean()
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)).size()
```

This gives the following output:

| Age |  |
| --- | --- |
| 0-14 | 2 |
| 15-29 | 1 |
| 30-44 | 3 |
| 45-59 | 1 |
| 60+ | 1 |

But I would like to have the average `Tip amount` for the groups as well.

| Age |  | Tip amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-14 | 2 | avg |
| 15-29 | 1 | avg |
| 30-44 | 3 | avg |
| 45-59 | 1 | avg |
| 60+ | 1 | avg |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)).agg({'Age': ['size'], 'Tip amount': ['mean']})
```

Comment: I get an error saying `Could not convert 1333,544447.... to numeric`

Comment: Usually '.' is used as the decimal separator. So you would have to convert the , to . first, e.g. by running
`df["Tip amount"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Tip amount"].astype(str).str.replace(',','.'))`

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to run my `.replace()`before

Comment: Would it be possible to put the new df in a bar Chart?

Comment: Sure, what kind of bar plot do you want?

Comment: I think a Bar Chart would make more sense. I tried `alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(size=15).encode(
    x='Age',
    y='Tip amount',
    tooltip=['Tip amount','Age']).properties(width=800)` but get a error due to the new `size`text

Comment: this removes the second header row (size & mean):
`df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(-1)`
does that help?

Comment: I get this error `Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242850/discussion-between-amy989-and-nicolaj-spiegelhauer).